# Substituting two points in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

One of the exercises in my eBook substitutes q - p and s - r.
My question is this; why did the book substitute in that order? Why not p - q and r - s?

[Here's an image of the exercise in my book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYdSU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was not neccessarily substition. What did happen was that the difference between the points determining the line was translated to the origin, which means that whereas **q** and **p** were "floating" in the plane before, the vector connecting the two is now emanating from the origin. The same was done for **s-r** - this makes it easier to compare the lines, as they coincide with these vectors.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand now. So q and p are just points floating at the given coordinates, and we found the difference between the two so we can work with the original line.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo Yes, in this case we are treating the vectors **p** and **q** as points in the plane. As these define the line $l_{1}$, they both lie on $l_{1}$. It follows from this that the vector connecting **p** and **q**, **q-p**, does too. Note that **q-p** is not the original line as **q-p** has a clear starting and ending point (it starts at the origin and ends at (-3, -2, 1)). It is simply a representative of the line. Try to make a drawing!

Answer (score 1):

In this case the order doesn’t matter. If a vector $\vec v$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec u$, then clearly so is $-\vec v$.

Comment: So the two lines end up being parallel regardless of the order.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo That’s right. You can think of the order as fixing a direction in which you trace the lines. Their being parallel or not is independent of this.